# How do I get TextBox in a GridView row when Edit button is clicked if the headers are not databound?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView`, and the header fields of the `GridView` are the items from a `ListBox` in my program. Therefore the number of columns generated is dynamic every time I run. Based on this, if I click the Edit button associated inside my `GridView`, how do I generate a `TextBox` for each cell of that row?

The .cs code I have written is:

```
protected void DONE4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel7.Visible = true;

    SqlDataAdapter mydat = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Profile_Instance FROM Profile_Master", con);
    DataSet dst = new DataSet();
    mydat.Fill(dst, "Table");
    ListBox3.Items.Clear();
    ListBox3.DataSource = dst.Tables[0];
    ListBox3.DataTextField = dst.Tables[0].Columns["Profile_Instance"].ColumnName;
    ListBox3.DataBind();

    int count = ListBox3.Items.Count;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow rw = default(DataRow);
    for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(ListBox1.Items[i].ToString(),
                                       System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        rw = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            rw[ListBox1.Items[i].ToString()] = " ";
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(rw);
    }

    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();

    foreach (GridViewRow grdRow in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        DropDownList bind_dropdownlist = new DropDownList();                                                    // defining the property of the DropDownList as bind_dropdownlist
        bind_dropdownlist = (DropDownList)(GridView2.Rows[grdRow.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("Pro_List"));   // finding the  DropDownList from the gridiew for binding
        SqlDataAdapter mydata = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Profile_Instance FROM Profile_Master", con);
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();                                                                           // binding the DropDownList with the dataset ds
        mydata.Fill(dset, "Table");
        bind_dropdownlist.DataSource = dset;
        bind_dropdownlist.DataTextField = "Profile_Instance";                                                   // set the DropDownList's DataTextField as designation which display the designation in the dropdownlist after fetching the data from database
        bind_dropdownlist.DataBind();
        bind_dropdownlist.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Choose Profile---", "-1"));
    }
}
```

The design code for the `GridView` is:

```xml
<asp:Panel ID="Panel7" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CellPadding="4"
        style="text-align: center; font-size: small" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">

        <Columns>                
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="Pro_List" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>                          
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Can someone please help me on this? I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not Binding `GridView` and still want to access the controls within it, you can use the `GridViewRow` property.

```
protected void grd_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) 
{
     GridViewRow selectRow = grd.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
     TextBox txtKj=(TextBox)selectRow.Cells[3].FindControl("txtKjId"); 
}
```

Comment: This is giving me an error : Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.Rows' cannot be used like a method.